# Problem in sending a list of values as a response to jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

using jquery Im selecting a value form a dropdown and sending it to action class.In action class im getting the list of values base on selected value.Can any one please tell how to get this list of values in jsp?

Comment: Please be more descriptive about what you want. You are saying you are getting the list of values and then ask how you get the list of values.

Answer (score 1):

In your action class you set a request attribute:
request.setAttribute("theList", listOfValues)

Then you can read it in the next JSP.
Using EL:

```
${theList}
```

Or even without setting it to the request (assuming no processing was needed):

```
${param.theList}
```

Or using a scriptlet (if you must...):

```
<%=request.getParameter("firstame")%>
```